# How to push a newly created branch in my local forked to remote upstream repo?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

I have forked of my upstream. In my local I created a new branch and pushed to origin with `git push -u origin <new feature branch>`, this has created a new branch on my forked repo. Now I want to push this  to be remote upstream. I can not push directly to remote only merge request can be submitted.

Thing is I can not see the `<new feature branch>` in remote upstream when trying to create new merge request. How can I create a merge request that will create and push the same  in forked to the remote upstream repo?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a merge request that will create and push the same in forked to the remote upstream repo?

This isn't possible with a merge request as `merging` will incorporate changes from the source branch (from your forked repo) to the destination branch (remote upstream repo) -- this won't create a new branch.

So generally you'd want to set the destination of your merge request to the one where you based your local branch off of.

Comment: so does that mean that if I am not privileged to push to upstream then I should not create a new branch from my local?

Comment: Not necessarily, you're free to create branches on your local repo as you wish but you can't push them upstream.